# Container div having fixed height on height:auto

Tags: html, css, firebug

I have `height:auto` on my container but it stops after the third div and makes the other divs return and move next to the third div on the left when they should be below it floating right. why wont my height go any further than my third div. Please go to [my site](http://www.michaelpelvay.com) if you need a visual aid.
FIXED THE PROBLEM NO NEED TO ANSWER THIS QUESTION ANYMORE!

```
#container{
margin:100px 50px 100px 300px;
min-width:500px;
max-width:1300px;
height:auto;
background-color:#26353c;
clear:both;
}

#portfolio{
float:right;
margin:100px -70px 0 0;
}

#resume{
float:right;
margin:15px -70px 0 0;
}

#aboutme{
float:right;
margin:15px -70px 0 0;
}

<div id="Lefttext">
<p>I have been in the Macomb Community Colleges MACA program earning my Web Specialist Degree. </p>
</div>
<div id="portfolio"><a href="portfolio.html"><img src="images/Portfolio.png" width="876" height="148" alt="Portfolio" /></a></div>
<div id="resume"><a href="resume.html"><img src="images/Resume.png" width="750" height="148" alt="Resume"/></a></div>
<div id="aboutme"><a href="about-me.html"><img src="images/About Me.png" width="624" height="148" alt="About me"/></a></div>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please try to ask clear questions, you will elicit better responses.

Comment: thought it was clear from "height is fixed but its on auto" meaning why wont my height go any further than my third div

Comment: `auto` is the default value of height, a div's height will automatically fit to the height of its contents. When you float objects they attempt to display inline, but because your images are so wide they will drop to the next line.

Comment: are you sure you mean height as looking quickly at it they are floating right, so when it comes to the end of the browser they will drop down, enlarge the browser? Also you only have three divs, do you mean aboutme drops down etc??

Comment: yes aboutme and every other div after that inside the container will be in the left side even if i do float right

Comment: im not a newbie to html and css im just stumped at this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The div getting out of your container are floating, you need to clear that. Just add this to your css :

```
.clearfloat {
    clear: both; 
}
```

And the last child of your `#container` must be `<div class="clearfloat"></div>`. Take a look at this article by [Chris Coyier](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/) (a CSS guru).

Comment: By doing this your container is expanding like this : http://s22.postimg.org/6a8x5kg2p/image.jpg instead of this : http://s14.postimg.org/keks3596p/image.jpg. This is not what you wanted ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a width to the container and add `float: right` to `#Lefttext`

Comment: i have a width to the container but thats not the problem and also if i named the css LEFT text why would i float it right

Comment: Is the width sufficient enough to fit both the left-nav and the menu? Also, why is the right menu so big? is this for mobile?

Comment: yes they both can fit i was just deleting the unimportant css to see if i could find the problem but no such luck and no its not for mobile

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say from your question, but I think what you're trying to achieve is right aligning these images on top of one another? If that is the case just try adding a line break between each div:

```
    <p>I have been in the Macomb Community Colleges MACA program earning my Web     Specialist Degree.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="portfolio"><a href="portfolio.html"><img src="http://michaelpelvay.com/images/Portfolio.png" width="876" height="148" alt="Portfolio" /></a>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div id="resume"><a href="resume.html"><img src="http://michaelpelvay.com/images/Resume.png" width="750" height="148" alt="Resume"/></a>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div id="aboutme"><a href="about-me.html"><img src="http://michaelpelvay.com/images/About Me.png" width="624" height="148" alt="About me"/>    </a>
    </div>
```

Here is a sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8fX46/).

Comment: `float:right` will right align the divs, but when you have 3 floated objects inside of a container they will try to display inline as opposed to on top of each other. Is this what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: im uploading a picture to my website to show u what i want to do